# When is ReDim necessary in dynamic arrays?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a short question about ReDim-ming dynamic arrays - more precisely in which cases is it required?

I understand I need to `ReDim Preserve array(x) As Variant` when adding entries into the array. Adjusting/changing existing information in an array works well like: `array(x) = "Added text " & array(x)`

But are there any other cases when I need to worry about ReDim or maybe even other special requirements when handling dynamic arrays?

I'm writing a code which will include large dynamic arrays that get data added from many different sources before For-looping through it to write the date into a list on another sheet. I can't let an error pop up in the future because I missed something.

Comment: ReDim is to redimension the array, if your array goes from 0 to 100 but you are expecting to increase, you ReDim 0 to 100 + x for example. You can `Dim array() As String` and then use `ReDim` to give it it's value later after you calculated how large you need it to be.

Comment: If you want to change the size of the array, you use ReDim, simple as that really.  :-)

Comment: `ReDim` as others have said just re-dimensions the last dimension of the array. This can be a bit slow if you are `ReDim`ing each loop. A much better way of handling it is to `ReDim` before your loop to the maximum size and then `ReDim Preserve` to the actual size after your `Loop`. You'll find it far quicker

Comment: Thanks guys! Just wanted a heads up - because I'm pretty good with arrays now, but everynow and again there were some moments where I wasn't sure.

Comment: You should check if it's not better to use a List or Dictionary.

Comment: Please [do not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311829/11683) put "solved" in the title and do not put the solution in the question.

Comment: I think @Damian should post his comment as answer and OP accept it, so the question can be closed.

Comment: I would put Damians Answer up but would like a little extended explanation of Tom's method, maybe with an example to make it an "official answer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReDim`is used to change the size of an array. You can `ReDim` an array not initialized like this:

`Dim arr() As Variant
x = 200
ReDim arr(1 to x)`

You can also do this on initialized arrays:

`Dim arr(1 to 2) As Variant
ReDim arr(1 to 5)` <-- will delete previous stored values

`ReDim Preserve arr(1 to 5)` <-- will preserve previous stored values

Note that using the  `Preserve` will only change the last dimension on multidimension arrays, so `Dim arr(1 to 5, 1 to 2)` if you want to keep your data using `ReDim Preserve` you can only change the second dimension from `1 to 2` to `1 to x`.

Like Tom said, changing the size of your array in every loop will impact on the performance so you should first calculate the maximum size of your array and then dimension it, or dimension the size way over what you need and lastly redim it to your needs when you end.